# $\phi$-torsion of a group

Tags: group-theory, definition, abelian-groups, group-homomorphism, torsion-groups

Let $\phi:G\to G$ be an endomorphism of an abelian group $G$. If $\phi$ is defined by $g\mapsto g^n$, then I already know that $G[\phi]:=G[n]=$ $n$-torsion of $G=\ker(\phi)$. But if $\phi$ is a general endomorphism, then is it still true that (the $\phi$ torsion of $G$) $G[\phi]:=\ker(\phi)$? I saw this notation in the context of Selmer group of an isogeny $\phi$.

Comment: Are you assuming that $G$ is abelian?  If not, the power map isn't generally an endomorphism.

Comment: When all you see is just abelian groups, you forget that nonabelian groups are really a thing :)

Comment: No worries.  I've seen the kernel of $\phi$ referred to as $\phi-$torsion, but I wouldn't think that was a universally familiar term. Makes sense, of course, and it is easy enough to define it in context.